# How to create a wrapper function for default knockout bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, data-binding

I am displaying a huge tabular structure with knockout. The user has the option to remove rows by clicking a checkbox on the row:

```
data-bind="checked: row.removed"
```

The problem is that the table has to be re-rendered on click, which on slow computers/browsers takes up to one or two seconds - the checkbox changes its state after the table has been rendered so the UI feels unresponsive. 
I would like to create a wrapper function that does the same thing as the default checked-binding but additionally displays a loader symbol - then hides it again after the checked binding did its job. Something like:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.checkedWithLoader = {
    update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
        loader.show();
        // call knockout's default checked binding here
        loader.hide();
    }
};
```

Is something like that possible? Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### How to access other bindings in a custom binding

You can use `ko.applyBindingsToNode`:

```
ko.applyBindingsToNode(element, { checked: valueAccessor() })
```

Knockout's source actively exposes this method ([here](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/bindingAttributeSyntax.js#L460)) and references it in an example on its own documentation page ([here](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html#note-2-post-processing-the-generated-options)).

It probably won't solve your issue with handling slow renders though...

### Handling slow updates

You could also create an extra layer in your viewmodel to build in the loading feature:

```
this.checked = ko.observable(false);

this.isLoading = ko.observable(false);
this.showLargeAndSlowTable = ko.observable(false);

this.checked.subscribe(function(isChecked) {
  this.isLoading(true);
  this.showLargeAndSlowTable(isChecked);
  this.isLoading(false);
}, this);
```

You'll need an `if` or `with` binding bound to `showLargeAndSlowTable`, and bind the checkbox value to `checked`.

In some cases, you might need to force a repaint between setting the `loading` observable and injecting the large data set. Otherwise, knockout and the browser can bundle these updates in to one frame.

You can achieve this by putting the `showLargeAndSlowTable` and `isLoading(false)` in a `setTimeout`, or by using a delayed/throttled additional observable that triggers the work after `isLoading`'s change has been given time to render:

```js
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    
    // The checkbox value that triggers the slow UI update
    this.showLargeTable = ko.observable(false);
    
    // Checkbox change triggers things
    this.showLargeTable.subscribe(updateUI)
    
    // Indicates when we're loading:
    this.working = ko.observable(false);
    this.delayedWorking = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      return self.working();
    }).extend({ throttle: 10 });
    
    // Instead of directly subscribing to `working`, we
    // subscribe to the delayed copy
    this.delayedWorking.subscribe(function(needsWork) {
      if (needsWork) {
        doWork();
        self.working(false);
      }
    });
    
    function updateUI(showTable) {
      if (showTable) {
        self.working(true); // Triggers a slightly delayed update
      } else {
        self.data([]);
      }
    }
    
    // Some data from doc. page to work with
    function doWork() {
      // (code only serves to mimic a slow render)
      for (var i = 0; i < 1499; i++) {
          self.data([]);
          self.data(data.reverse());
      }
    };
    
    var data = [
        { name: 'Alfred', position: 'Butler', location: 'London' },
        { name: 'Bruce', position: 'Chairman', location: 'New York' }
    ];
    
    // Some data to render
    this.data = ko.observableArray([]);
    
}


ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```css
.is-loading {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.is-loading::after {
  content: "LOADING";
  color: white;
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<label>
  <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: showLargeTable, disable: working">Show slowly rendered table
</label>

<table data-bind="css: { 'is-loading': working }">
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: position"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: location"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<em>Example based on the <a href="http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/deferred-updates.html">knockout docs</a></em>
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there absolutely no way to "pause" knockout's bindings completely? Something like ko.pause() / ko.resume() would be very handy.

Comment: I'd resort to using `throttle`, `rateLimit` and `deferred` to move updates to the end of the javascript stack. Of course, you can always postpone writing to the actual data-bound observables through general javascript features such as `setTimeout` as well. A more drastic approach could be to call `ko.cleanNode` to remove the bindings and reapply them later on, but I would advise against it...